# How to make Bison not exit when it calls yyerror

Tags: yacc, bison

When my parser is scanning a source file and some syntax is incorrect, and it calls yyerror, I want it to display the error message, but continue parsing the file to potentially display more errors.  However, every time the parser calls yyerror, it displays the error message and then exits?  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution: http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/bison_9.html